# WiFi router installation/signal problem

Tags: wireless-networking, router, signal

I got 2 questions concerning my WiFi router:

1. I got my D-Link router 3 years ago and recently the signal is getting weaker especially toward the end of the day. Why? Sometime it's so weak that I couldn't even surf the net.
2. I'm planning to buy a new N-Router soon. Can I install router without plugging the LAN cable to my PC?(Connect "wirelessly" instead).  since my PC is located far away from the cable/router.

Comment: You might be getting interference from a neighbors wifi... try changing the channel it runs on. Try using http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/ to see what channel is not being used.

Comment: Yes you can connect wirelessly but you will need to connect to the device with a wire first to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

1. DO experience the signal drops at the same time every day? It's possible your router's being exposed to the elements (sudden temperature change due to sunlight) or you have a neighbor with faulty equipment (some old old microwave ovens or faulty cordless phones can sometimes interfere with wifi). It's hard to say with any certainty what could be causing your problem. You could try moving your router to another part of your home and see if that alleviates any problems.
2. Many routers require the setup/install to be done via a LAN cable. There are a few, however, that allow setup via wifi. You'll have to read the user manual or online reviews of any router you wish to buy.

Answer (score 0):

> ...the signal is getting weaker especially toward the end of the day...

This may be caused by other people in your local area with wireless routers interfering with your signal.  You should try changing the channel your WiFi is transmitting on to see if this improves your signal.

> Can I install router without plugging the LAN cable to my PC?

That depends on the make and model of router.

Some will have the wireless enabled by default with no encryption, some will have the ability to link your computer to the WiFi with encryption by pressing a "WPS" button on the router, and some will have the wireless completely disabled.

Either way it's safest to link the router up to the computer for configuration - at least for the WiFi configuration portion.  If you configure the WiFi next to your computer, then move the router to its final destination once you are happy with the WiFi configuration you can then proceed with the Internet configuration remotely.